# Array index operator as a method reference

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

If have an array of `String` and I want the first element. It is possible to write a method reference for this in Java 8? For example

```
String[] strings = new String[] {"aa","bb","cc","dd"};
Function<String[], String> first = Array::[0];    // this should be "aa"
```

What I found is that

```
Function<String[], String> first = (strings -> strings[0]);
```

works, but I want to know if it is posible. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Ok, seems it is not possible. Bonus question: it is possible with a `List<String>`, then? Something like:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("aa","bb","cc","dd");
Function<List<String>, String> first = List::get(0); // this don't work, obviously
```

Comment: Nope, there's no built-in way to do this.  You can create your own method, sure, but that's essentially what lambdas would do anyway.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question IMO. You can't pass values into method references, as you demonstrated with `List::get(0)`. What would be very useful and semantically consistent with other method reference types would be using the *index* and input parameter, like this: `IntFunction<String> lookup = strings::[]`, which would be equivalent to `i -> string[i]`. And possibly `BiFunction<String[], Integer> lookup = String[]::[]`, equivalent to `(strings, i) -> strings[i]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest thing I could figure out.

```
 // For an array, 
 final Function<String[], String> firstArr =
    ((Function<Optional<String>,String>)Optional::get)
      .<Stream<String>>compose(Stream::findFirst)
      .compose(Arrays::stream);

 // For a collection
 final Function<List<String>, String> firstCol =
    ((Function<Optional<String>,String>)Optional::get)
      .<Stream<String>>compose(Stream::findFirst)
      .compose(Collection::stream);
```

Not exactly a clean and clear one liner.

The best answer is `array -> array[0]` and `list -> list.get(0)`  These are the clearest and most concise.

Comment: The type of `firstCol` should be `Function<List<String>, String>` rather than `Function<String[], String>`. Besides that, if you are going to compose functions, `((Function<List<String>,Iterator<String>>)List::iterator).andThen(Iterator::next)` might be easier…

Comment: Ah, you're probably right about the andThen.  Still getting up to speed on 1.8, only been using it a few weeks.

Comment: Actually, I have a better design... going to post another answer.

Comment: I think this is the better answer even if it is not a one liner.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your own:

```
public class MyArrayUtils {
    public static <T> T getFirst(T[] a) {
        return a[0];
    }
}

Function<String[], String> first = MyArrayUtils::<String>getFirst;
```

Comment: It would be even nicer if you made it generic instead of specific to `String`.

Comment: True, change made ;-)

Comment: You don’t need to qualify the method reference; `Function<String[], String> first = MyArrayUtils::getFirst;` works. Besides that, I don’t see any advantage over a simple lambda expression.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function for arrays. However, [streams do have such function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--), and [arrays are convertible to streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

```
Function<Stream<String>,Optional<String>> f = Stream::findFirst;
String[] data = new String[] {"aa","bb","cc","dd"};
Optional<String> res = f.apply(Arrays.stream(data));
System.out.println(res.get());
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BsD2zw)